# Laravel: 1 folder, 2 environments

Tags: laravel, iis, server

I have a question about a bad practice in Laravel.

I have only one server folder available for Laravel (in IIS).
There, I have the production site.

If I want to add a copy for development and testing against the test database, where must I place it?

Inside the production's version public folder? I donth think because it's unsafe. Sure will be an obvious best practice for that.

Comment: Usually, the development environment is either on a different permanent server or on a local development machine. If you must have it on the same physical server as the production environment then create a different directory for it and configure IIS to serve that under a different (sub)domain name.  e.g. if your site is example.com then your development site could be dev.example.com and it could be behind basic auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a new port for it. 
Example: 
**Config Virtual host with Production site:** 
Create a configuration file our laravel production project by typing the following commands

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano production.conf
```

In the production.conf file created paste the following content to the file and close it after saving. 
Replace laravelproduction.com with the domain name of your website inside the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravelproduction.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/production>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the newly created .conf file and disable the default .conf which is pre-created by apache and enable mode rewrite for this to function appropriately. These are the comand to help you do that.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf (disable the default .conf file) 
sudo a2ensite production.conf (enables the newly created .conf file) 
sudo a2enmod rewrite (enables the rewrite)
```

Also, restart your apache server so that it can pick the changes that you have made by typing this command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Config Virtual Host With Dev site**  
Create a configuration file our laravel dev project by typing the following commands

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano dev.conf
```

In the dev.conf file created paste the following content to the file and close it after saving.

```
Listen 8100
<VirtualHost *:8100>
    ServerName laraveldev.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/dev>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the newly created .conf file and disable the default .conf which is pre-created by apache and enable mode rewrite for this to function appropriately. These are the comand to help you do that.

```
sudo a2ensite dev.conf
```

Finally restart your apache server so that it can pick the changes that you have made by typing this command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This is how I usually use it. I hope to help you. ^_^